# How to identify correct version of spring-cloud.version in a springboot microservice client

Tags: spring-boot, maven, microservices, pom.xml, netflix-eureka

How to remove error from Spring boot micro-service application using spring cloud eureka client pom.xml file What would be the reason while the version is default generated by **start.spring.io**

```
 <properties>
         <java.version>11</java.version>
         <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
```

**The pom.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>order-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>order-service</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                ...
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Can anyone find the reason of error in the file, Thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't see anything thats' wrong. What error do you get?

Comment: There is no error inside code but file shows red mark. when I changed the version with `<spring-cloud.version>2020.0.1</spring-cloud.version>` then red mark from pom.xml file has been disappeared. Is there any version compatibility issues?

Comment: Where are red marks in your IDE (Which IDE are you using? Which  version of it?)? Does the build work on plain command line?

Comment: Error shows in pom.xml file in Project Explorer Project file structure tree. I am using Eclipse IDE of  Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0) I build and run inside IDE. I am not using command.